# Why Windows doesn't support ext4 if everything an OS sees are bytes sequences

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I am studying  Operating Systems and my teacher sent us this:

"In relation to file systems, is correct:"

And the right answer is:

"Files can be structured in many ways, and this does not matter to the Operating System, because everything it sees are bytes sequence."

If that's true, why can't all OS use every kind of file system?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#File_systems_and_operating_systems

Comment: They surely can in theory. But someone need to write the code to do deal with the different formats of a particular filesystem - and there's many combinations of operating systems and filesystems for which noone has done that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t because of technology; it is possible to write an arbitrary on-disk format file system for almost every OS(*).

The problem may be in the business case, that MicroSoft doesn’t see a benefit in providing this level of integration with Linux.  Maybe they view this file system as inherently fragile in comparison with their own, and do not which to expose their customers to such a risk.  That is an excuse usually trotted out by Apple when what they really mean is *lock-in*; and I suspect that is the case with MicroSoft.  While the virtues of Apple and Google are questionable, the case against MicroSoft was proven.

(*) - at the worst, you could loopback an NFS or CIFS mount onto a local demon which worked with the on-disk format.